# How do I animate my object with empties without breaking all of my other animations?

Tags: animation, parent, empty

I am having an issue with this model. It has to be a functional technical model (meaning all of the doors and flaps must be able to move). I have done that but now that I need to animate moving the entire object, I am struggling because it seems that no matter what I do my other animations break. I have tried parenting everything to the main body of the aircraft, that breaks my stuff that doesn't have the mirror modifier. If I parent everything to an empty, it breaks a lot of my animations on other empties. If anyone is able to help [here is the link to my .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ShQXvEFFVu-Y3E4q4HCXGt3j2hEiTLgT/view?usp=sharing)

UPDATE: OK sorry for the late reply. After doing what you said, I realized what was happening. I was overwriting the parented objects. So by following what was suggested here, I was able to fix my issue.

Comment: Hello, it seems like you haven't chosen a solution, you first need ton choose how you want everything to be parented, will you parent everything to the main body, to an empty, to an armature? etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome to Blender SE.

Parenting isn't too hard if you are willing to try out some things.

1. create an empty (i call it master)

Then you should be clear about **what** you have to parent, and what you must not parent.

All meshes/objects which will be moved/animated by the armature you must not parent to that master, because they already will be moved by the armature.
If the armature has no parent, parent it to the master.
If the armature's parent has no parent, parent that to the master (and so on).
So don't change existing parents. Parent armatures (without parent) to your master.
I would use ctrl-P -> keep offset to parent all (of course not all, only that things, which should fly with your airplane) to your master.

Then you will get:

[image]

Note: some animations weren't working in your uploaded blend file, so they won't work in mine.

repaired blend file:

[image]

Hint: you should use https://blend-exchange.com/ to upload your blend file.

Happy blending!

Comment: I was waiting for some Geonodes, what's happening Chris, maybe a bit of covid?

Comment: I will try this and update later today on whether I was able to get it to work.